# Dependencies in lubuntu - libtirpc cannot be installed due to broken dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, package, rpc, libc, dpkg

I want to install `rpcbind` but it needs some other packages. I'm installing one by one (don't know if there's an easy way of doing that) and when I reach `liptirpc` it disallows me to install due to broken dependencies.

```
Selecting previously unselected package libtirpc1:i386.
(Reading database ... 145711 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libtirpc1_0.2.2-5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libtirpc1:i386 (0.2.2-5) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtirpc1:i386:
 libc6:i386 (2.19-10ubuntu2.3) breaks libtirpc1 (<< 0.2.3) and is installed.
  Version of libtirpc1:i386 to be configured is 0.2.2-5.

dpkg: error processing package libtirpc1:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtirpc1:i386
```

I've already  done `install -f` but when I try again the error remains...
I have no debian repositories on sources.list as you can check:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libc6 locales

libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-10ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 2.19-10ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-10ubuntu2.3 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-17
  Candidate: 2.13+git20120306-17
 Version table:
 *** 2.13+git20120306-17 0
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What am I doing wrong?